# How do I make a process a daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon

I have some commands or processes that need to be turned into daemons in my system. I have tried using `nohup`, but it is not working for processes.

How can I make a process a daemon?

Comment: What is unclear about this question? Genuinely curious.

Comment: What *exactly* have you tried and what exactly didn't work? The normal way to start a daemon (or in general a process which you want to become a daemon) is to run it from an init script / systemd service unit.

Comment: @AlexP Note that I didn't ask the question, I answered it. My answer mentioned a systemd unit, but even after the answer was posted the question got most of the close votes. Btw. running a program from an init script does not make it a daemon, you need code in the program to daemonize the program, or use systemd which does that for you.

Comment: @JohanMyréen: I apologize for my error.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to define a Systemd service unit. Systemd takes care of what needs to be done. If you don't want to go that route, take a look at the `daemon` library function.